# docker compose run with command error

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

From this [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/), it seems like that I can execute a single command from a service like this:

```
docker-compose run SERVICE CMD
```

But when I run

```
docker-compose up pwa npm test
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: No such service: npm
```

From my configurations, it will execute `npm start`, but I'd like to know how to execute other commands.

### Files

Dockerfile:

```
From node:8
WORKDIR /app
copy package.json /app/
RUN npm install --quiet
CMD npm start
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  pwa:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
      - ./public:/app/public
```

### Versions

Docker version: 17.03

Docker compose version: 1.11.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As docs say, the command is `docker-compose run`, not `docker-compose up`. The later expects all service names.

Do as this:

```
docker-compose run pwa npm test
```